# HP ProBook 430 G2 Notebook wont switch on

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure

When the power adapter of my [HP ProBook 430 G2 notebook](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c04355372) is plugged in, the caps lock and power buttons flash, no particular pattern just on/off on/off continually. There's no other signs of life, no fans spinning up , no output to the screen and no beep codes. When looking up what the flashing lights mean on the HP support site this combination isn't dealt with.

What I've tried and additional details:

1. I'm in UK so power is 240v AC.
2. Same result with the battery in or out and adapter plugged in.
3. I've tested the output voltage from the adapter and it's 19v as
   expected.
4. Same result if I plug adapter into a different wall socket with no
   intermediate power extension cables.
5. The power adapter is rated for well over the 45w required.
6. I've tried removing battery then holding power button down for 60
   seconds and then reconnecting power with no result.
7. I've also tried taking out the CMOS battery and reinstalling it.
8. It wont power up on battery, I presume the battery is in need of
   charge.

Comment: 1) Will it power up on battery without the AC adapter? 2) Do you get the same result if you connect the power adapter power cord to a different wall outlet? 3) Please make sure you are plugged directly into the wall outlet without any extension cord or grounding adapter 4) Are you in the US, and if not, where? 5) Do you get this if you remove the battery and reconnect the power adapter? (see page 30 http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c04784551 ) 6) If you have a voltmeter or multimeter, do you get 19 volts AC from the power supply? 7) is the power adapter rated for 45W per its label?

Comment: Please click [edit] and advise results of 1-7. Please do not use Add Comment; instead add this useful information to the question with [edit].

Comment: Power button continuous flash means insufficient power.

Comment: @K7AAY thanks for your guidance. I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: I have the same model and a month or two ago I added a second stick of RAM. I got the flashing lights as you describe when I tried to power up after the upgrade. I swapped the new and old sticks and then it powered up. So poorly seated RAM might be one cause?

Comment: Turned out to be my universal power supply couldn't power it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take your lappie to your Friendly neighborhood PC repair shoppe. I would call around first to make sure a) they are friendly, and b) they have the appropriate 45W power supply on hand for your HP ProBook 430 G2 notebook. Remove the battery, put their power adapter on your laptop and see if it will boot.

Why? A power adapter can give you 19V when tested, but once you put it on line and present it with a computer to run, the voltage can sag 'under load' which would cause this problem.

Should this work, it's New Power Adapter Time, and there they are, ready to sell you a replacement. Handy, innit?

Should this not work, well, remove the HDD/SSD from the lappie following the instructions in http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c04784551 , and ponder if it's worth repair, or if you have the shilling rattling in your pocket to replace it with new or used.  They can sell you a USB-SATA adapter with which to connect the drive with your info to whatever PC you will be using henceforth.

Comment: Think I'll buy a replacement adapter and test then sell the piece of crap for parts if no joy. It's a 4th gen intel i5 and would be nice to resurrect and have as my main laptop but if it's too expensive then I'll chop it into parts and sell what does work. Appreciate the input.

Comment: Bought replacement power adapter and it now boots to bios. Never had my universal power adapter fail to power up a laptop before... I guess there's a first time for everything.